# Sum of Dice and Coin Problem

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> You have six balanced coins and two balanced dice tossed altogether. 
>   If Z is the sum of the scores on the dice and the number of heads, what is the variance and mean of Z?

My attempt: 
I constructed two separate charts with sum on dice and number of heads each, such that pdf of each chart sums up to 1. I am trying to find combinations that will produce the combined result(or sum) of these two charts from 2 to 18.

Manually finding all the combinations and multiplying them with probability seems like too much work, there has to be an easier approach to this...so my question is:

Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple expected value argument to solve for the mean and variance. The expected value is synonymous to the mean you are seeking. The expected sum on the dice is $6 * 3.5 = 21.$ The expected number of heads is $\frac{1}{2} * 2 = 1.$ The mean is just $21 + 1 = \boxed{22}.$